# Seq.unfold explanation in F#

Tags: f#, seq.unfold

I am trying to create a sequence lazily by using F#.

The sequence is defined as follows:

> The nth term of the sequence of
>   triangle numbers is given by, tn =
>   ½n(n+1); so the first ten triangle
>   numbers are:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55,
>   ...

Here is what I have so far but it dosn't seem to work:

```
let tri_seq = 1.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> match x with                                         
                                          | _ -> Some (x, 0.5*x*(x + 1.0)))
```

Thank you very much who can help me figure out how unfold works. Thanks

**Edit:** I marked the first answer as correct but it dosnt work, however I slightly modified it and it worked.

```
let tri_seq = 1.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (0.5 * x * (x + 1.0),x + 1.0))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, why do you use `match` if you've got only one case?

```
let tri_seq = 1.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (x, 0.5 * x * (x + 1.0)))
```

Second, what “doesn't seem to work”? Are you aware that you produce an infinite list?

/Edit: For completeness’ sake, here’s the correct solution, which the OP found himself and posted as a comment:

```
let tri_seq = 
    1.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (0.5 * x * (x + 1.0), x + 1.0))
```

Comment: I tried that, but the sequence just returns one..

> tri_seq;;
val it : seq<float> = seq [1.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0; ...]

Comment: let tri_seq = 1.0 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (0.5 * x * (x + 1.0),x + 1.0)) is what i needed. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to the code that Brian posted is to use recursion instead of imperative 'while' loop:

```
let tri = 
  let rec loop(n, diff) = seq { 
    yield n        
    yield! loop(n + diff, diff + 1.0) }
  loop(1.0, 2.0)
printfn "%A" (tri |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.to_list)
```

It is far less efficient (so you have to be a bit careful here...), but it is more idiomatic functional solution, so it may be easier to see what the code does.

Comment: Thankyou, but i have no idea what the "Seq { }" does, not "yield" keyword, and lets not talk about the "!". If you can take some time to explain, it would be appreciated!

Comment: Not an expert, but Seq {} means make me a sequence out of this. yield is same as C# - means send back value and wait for calling code to ask for next. yield! is (I believe) like Seq.concat - flattens the seq returned from recursive call and does a yield on each element.

Comment: a bit of effort can be made to have at least `loop` be tail recursive, otherwise this is not going to scale anywhere

Comment: @pqnet The F# compiler actually handles recursive `seq` expressions nicely, so this pattern works fine (it's not like `foreach(x in y) yield x` in C# which would be problematic)

Comment: @TomasPetricek you are right, the function is actually a tail call since sequences are lazy, and `loop` returns a sequence, which is then returned as a continuation of the current sequence. If `yield` and `yield!` were in opposite order, that would be problematic, but like this it is possible to optimize

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative:

```
let tri = seq {
    let n = ref 1.0
    let diff = ref 2.0
    while true do
        yield !n
        n := !n + !diff
        diff := !diff + 1.0
    }

printfn "%A" (tri |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.to_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old one, but i cant figure out why using float when you are sure that x * (x + 1) is an even number and indeed divisible by 2.
So I would simply use this one instead (not much difference i know but at least you have an int seq):

```
let tri_seq = 1 |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (x * (x + 1) / 2 , x + 1)) 

tri_seq |> Seq.take 6 |> Seq.toList //[1; 3; 6; 10; 15; 21]
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ct3k5t)

(Unless you dealing with huge numbers of course....)