# How to generate an array of exponential weights?

Tags: f#

I am trying to do an "unfold" - (I think), by starting with an initial value, applying some function to it repeatedly, and then getting a sequence as a result.

In this example, I'm trying to start with 1.0, multiply it by .80, and do it 4 times, such that I end up with an array = [| 1.0; 0.80; 0.64; 0.512 |]

VS 2010 says I'm using "i" in an invalid way, and that mutable values cannot be captured by closures - so this function does not compile.  Can anyone possibly suggest a clean approach that actually works?  Thank you.

```
let expSeries seed fade n = 
//take see and repeatedly multiply it by the fade factor n times...
    let mutable i = 0;
    let mutable weight = seed;
    [| while(i < n) do
          yield weight;
          weight <- weight * fade |]

let testWeights = expSeries 1.0 0.80 4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let exp_series seed fade n =  
    Array.init (n) (fun i -> seed * fade ** (float i))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. Very concise, and I get it.  Cheers.

Comment: Although I like the approach, this isn't very idiomatic F# (and doesn't compile on F# 1.9.9.9); more commonly one would use `*` in place of `*.` and `float` in place of `float_of_int`.

Comment: @kvb - I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: I mostly write ocaml, so those things will slip through the cracks. I have noticed a lot of divergence of F# lately, so I might be best not answering these questions anymore. :)

Comment: Following @kvb's answer, I would say this i not even idiomatic functional programming.  One would expect to see a definition of a sequence, and a "take n" out of that sequence.

Comment: That would work better with lazy eval. ocaml has this, but it is much more verbose. Seq are lazy then? Either way, I disagree with you. I don't see why using the closed form Solution to the elements of a sequence isn't FP.

Answer (score 2):

I think this recursive version should work.

```
let expSeries seed fade n = 
   let rec buildSeq i weight = seq {
       if i < n then
           yield weight;
           yield! buildSeq (i + 1) (weight * fade) 
   } 
   buildSeq 0 seed
   |> Seq.toArray
```

Comment: Think of it like this, (*man I hope I don't make a fool of myself*) the `buildSeq` function represents the plan to build the array and `Seq.toArray` function actually builds the array from the plan.

Comment: ok - that does make sense.  I'm still getting used to writing recursive functions, and the "yield!" syntax.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @fs_tech - A few months ago I would have said the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [anwer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533633/seq-unfold-explanation-in-f), you can create an unfold, and take a number of values of it:

```
let weighed startvalue factor  = 
  startvalue |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (x, factor * x))

let fivevalues = weighed 1.0  .8   |> Seq.take 5
```

Comment: I would recommend the arguments to `weighed` not be tupled so you don't have to use the parenthesis and comma everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly use an unfold, here's how:

```
let expSeries seed fade n =
  Seq.unfold 
    (fun (weight,k) -> 
      if k > n then None 
      else Some(weight,(weight*fade, k+1)))
    (seed,1)
  |> Array.ofSeq

let arr = expSeries 1.0 0.80 4
```

Note that the reason your original code won't work is that mutable bindings can't be captured by closures, and sequence, list, and array expressions implicitly use closures.